# Swift3.0におけるjsonパースについて

Tags: swift, ios, json, swift3

Swift2.2からSwift3.0にソースコードの移行を取り組んでいます。

JSONデータを取得して表示するアプリを作成しています。

```
for item in items as! NSArray {
```

上記の該当ソースコードでフィールドitemが複数要素となっていましてその複数要素を定数itemsとしてNSArrayにキャストして1要素を定数itemに取り出しています。以前のSwift2.2では正しく動作していたのですが、Swift3.0ではNSArrayにキャストがうまく動作せずに修正方法に苦慮しております。

アドバイスをいただけないでしょうか？

**[Swift3.0に変換したソースコード]**

```
var okashiList :[(maker:String, name:String, link:String, image:String)] = []

func searchOkashi(keyword : String){

    let keyword_encode = keyword.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!

    let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default, delegate:nil, delegateQueue:OperationQueue.main)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: URLRequest(url: Foundation.URL(string: "http://www.sysbird.jp/toriko/api/?apikey=guest&format=json&keyword=\(keyword_encode)&max=10&order=r")!), completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in

        do {

            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! NSDictionary

            if let items = json.object(forKey: "item") {

                for item in items as! NSArray {

                    // コンパイルエラーが発生
                    guard let maker = item.object(forKey: "maker") else {
                        continue
                    }

                    // コンパイルエラーが発生
                    guard let name = item.object(forKey: "name") else {
                        continue
                    }

                    // コンパイルエラーが発生
                    guard let link = item.object(forKey: "url") else {
                        continue
                    }

                    // コンパイルエラーが発生
                    guard let image = item.object(forKey: "image") else {
                        continue
                    }

                    let data = (maker as! String,name as! String,link as! String,image as! String)

                    self.okashiList.append(data)

                }
            }

        } catch {
            // エラー
        }

    })
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

簡単に言うと、`NSDictionary`, `NSArray`の値型がSwift3になって`AnyObject`から`Any`に変更されたので、取り扱いが難しくなっています。(Swift2の時点でも、それらをSwiftのDictionary型かArray型にキャストすることができたはずなので、そうしていれば移行はもう少し簡単だったのですが。)

対応としては`item.object(forKey: "image")`のような記述を片っ端から`(item as! NSDictionary).object(forKey: "image")`か`(item as AnyObject).object(forKey: "image")`(後者がXcodeのサジェスチョン)のように書き換えてしまえば良いのですが(そういえば`objectForKey(_:)`もSwift2の時代から使う必要はなく`item["image"]`のように書けたはずです)、今後のことも考えると、できるだけSwift的な書き方をしておいた方が移行は楽になるでしょう。

`do {}`の内側だけを書き直してみるとこんな形になります。

```
            // 受け取ったJSONデータをパース（解析）して格納します。
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! [String: AnyObject]

            self.okashiList.removeAll()

            if let items = json["item"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {

                for item in items {

                    guard let maker = item["maker"] as? String else {
                        continue
                    }

                    guard let name = item["name"] as? String else {
                        continue
                    }

                    guard let link = item["url"] as? String else {
                        continue
                    }

                    guard let image = item["image"] as? String else {
                        continue
                    }

                    let okashi = (maker,name,link,image)

                    self.okashiList.append(okashi)
                }
                //TableViewを更新する
                self.tableview.reloadData()
            }
```

`json["item"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]`の部分は元のコードを見る限り`json["item"] as? [[String: String]]`として良いように思えるのですが、使っていないフィールドにString以外のものが含まれているとうまく動かない可能性があるので、上記のようにしておきました。
(これに限らず、元のJSONデータのサンプルを示しておいた方が、回答が書きやすくなるので、できればJSONデータのテキスト表現をご質問中に記載してもらった方が良いですね。上記のコードもまだ何か不備があるかもしれませんが、その際はコメント等でお知らせください。)

お試しください。

---

(補足)

- `[String: AnyObject]`の部分は`[String: Any]`の方が(Swift3の方向性的には)良いような気もするのですが、Objective-Cの`id`型を`Any`としてimportする動作は最近導入されたばかりで、まだ安定していないような気がしたので、とりあえず`AnyObject`にしてあります。(簡単なテストデータで見る限りどちらでも動くようです。)
- `.allowFragments`の指定は、結果を`NSDictionary`や`[String: AnyObject]`にキャストするならば無い方が良いので削除しました。単独の文字列や数値といったJSONとしては不正なデータが返ってきた時に、`as!`によるアプリのクラッシュではなく、`JSONSerialization`のerrorとしてキャッチできるようになります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。確認します。

Comment: うまく動作しました。本当にありがとうございました。